# TinyMCE and br : can't set br as a valid element

Tags: tinymce

I have a paragraph which I am pasting in tinyMCE:

Here is the paragraph:

```
<p>1 aaaaaaaaaaaaa<br />bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
```

I have set `p` and `br` as valid elements in the tinyMCE but I am loosing the `br` and I don't know why.

May be because my `br` is like `<br />` and not `<br>`?

If I will delete completely the valid elements option, I am then getting also the `<br />`.

Do you know how can I enable the `<br />` as a valid element in tinyMCE?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I wonder how `br` becomes XHTML `br` in your code? Because, usually, the tags are managed by tinyMCE itself, not by user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @raina77ow. In fact, I am pasting a paragraph form pdf, I realy need this. Doing that, The linebreaks become <br />.

Comment: Well, this is really weird. I've created a [tinyMCE fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/hWbaab) just to check the behavior you wrote about - and voila, it happily parses both `<br>` and `<br />`. Can you make your own fork on its basis to show your problem in more details?

Comment: Ouh, I have found the solution, thanks to you @raina77ow, the problem was that I had a space between p and br like that: valid_elements: "p, br" and it shuld be valid_elements: "p,br". Very stupid misteki from me, I am realy sorry. Can you please answer the question, I can then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinyMCE [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) option allows to specify wide range of rules to 'normalize' the document: it's powerful, but it's quite strict in its syntax. Particularly speaking, one shouldn't use whitespace as additional separator of the rules.

For example, to restrict valid elements to `<p>` and `<br />` only, this line should be used:

```
...
valid_elements: 'p,br' // not valid_elements: 'p, br'
...
```